# Рамка для блока в виде 4 уголков

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите как правильно реализовать такие рамки для блока?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При наведении должны менять цвет.

Comment: решение оказалось полезным или я не так вас понял?)

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
div:before,
div:after,
div span:before,
div span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
div:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
}
div:after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
div span:before {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
}
div span:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
div:hover:before,
div:hover:after,
div:hover span:before,
div:hover span:after {
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div><span>BLOCK</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Способ реализации через `flexbox` и псевдоклассы:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.mainBlock {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 2px rgba(222, 222, 222, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 2px rgba(222, 222, 222, 1);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 2px rgba(222, 222, 222, 1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.mainBlock:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(222, 222, 222, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(222, 222, 222, 1);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(222, 222, 222, 1);
}

div.mainBlock:hover>div.borderBlock:before,
div.mainBlock:hover>div.borderBlock:after,
div.mainBlock:hover>div.borderBlock>:first-child:before,
div.mainBlock:hover>div.borderBlock>:first-child:after {
  border-color: green;
}

div.borderBlock {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

div.borderBlock:before,
div.borderBlock:after,
div.borderBlock>:first-child:before,
div.borderBlock>:first-child:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-color: orange;
  border-style: solid;
  content: ' ';
}

div.borderBlock:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

div.borderBlock:after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

div.borderBlock>:first-of-type:before {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

div.borderBlock>:first-of-type:after {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='mainBlock'>
  <div class="borderBlock">
    <div class="content">
      <p>the content has to be here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```